# Java Application on network environment

Tags: java, mysql, percona

I'm developing an application using Java & MySQL Database, the application is a Desktop Application working in network environment.
The Application has some static content that is loaded from the database when starting the application.
if the super user made some change for some variables, i need to enforce the network users to restart the application so they can load the new variables.

What idea or code do I need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement something like this.

[Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Or maybe you can have a "ConfigTable" in your database, with property, value, expiration time.

So, when the admin updates some value, the other applications in the network can pool the new value.

[Take a look to JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/)

Regarding the pooling approach, (We don't have enough information to give you the best solution) you could try something like this.

A notification_table with ID, Event (Event is something that you know, maybe load new images, etc)

Workflow

1) The clients pool from this table every X seconds, filtering with ID > lastNotificationId (that needs to be saved in local file)
2) The client applies the new events.
3) The client updates the local file with new notificationId.

Comment: This what i'm looking for but could you please give the way to implement in way that not hit the performance.

Comment: Sorry, you mean Observer or JGroups?

Comment: If admin did the changes then these changes will be stored in the database table, the other clients application checking this table every 10 seconds since it will be a central database, if there is any changes then the application will refresh these values.

Comment: Ok. There is several factors to keep in mind. Do you need a "real time" changes propagation? Which is your "update windows". The simplest solution is that the application pool the config table every X seconds. A more elegant solution is add JGroups. Basically, with JGroups you don't need to "pull", the framework notify when something you are expecting happens.

Comment: OK that what i need to be explains the JGroups i need the fast keys to resolve this.

Comment: A quickly and elegant solution may not be possible. If you are running  against some schedule, maybe you need to go with the pooling approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what do you really need to do. But what I normally do is to tell the user that the changes will only have effect when the application is restarted. After that the user is responsible for restarting the application.
If you want to do it automatically you just need to refresh the changed data at the moment they get changed

Answer (score 0):

there are many solutions for that usecase. I would set a timestamp to your object. When the admin changes that object the timestamp will be updated on server side to the current date. After deliver the object to the client, the client has to compare the received object with that one which is currently used on client side. If the timestamp is not equal you can show a warning dialog. If you have the architecture that solution is very easy to implement...

Comment: Aha, this a good idea, so if the Admin made changes i will make auto insert to database table "Warnings" client side will check this table each 10 seconds, but is there a way when inserting in MySQL table the database send the notification to clients?

Comment: no... In my solution you assign the timestamp as class member attribute to the business object. If the object has its own database relation you have to expand that relation with a new timestamp attribute too. I think you store the objects anywhere on client so when the client calls the server and the server delivers the new objects you take your client object and compare it with the server object(timestamps). If the timestamp is not equal the admin must changed the object on server side.
Your solution is also possible but a little bit awkward. Why calling the server when not realy necessary?

Comment: OK this object should be selected from database to be compared to the current one, but did you mean doing the select when only the client need to get data?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store your data in a container where you can overwrite the values? This way you don't have to restart the application, only refresh data on-the-fly.

This way you can redefine the content of a `MessageBundle`, a `Properties`, or whatever container object you use to store the data.